# What happens to the process on an uncaught exception in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

It's possible a better title would be "what does LogCat actually monitor?"

I'm building and testing apps using Android Studio and either the emulator or an attached device. Sometimes when my app throws an exception and crashes, I continue to see messages showing up in the LogCat window of Android Studio. I would have expected that the process for my application has died, and the default filter in the LogCat window of "Show only selected application" would mean that I shouldn't see any additional messages. But that doesn't seem to be the case - it seems like either my process is still running, or I'm picking up messages from other processes. What's happening?

Comment: so you are not using some code at the application class level to catch the uncaught exception?

Comment: Correct - these are dummy POC apps, so I'm not terribly concerned with error handling. I am interested in what the output on my screen actually means though.